# How to Implement Hashmap in Pojo class in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Can anyone tell "how to create HashMap in Pojo class.
like I have

```
String semesterMap;
Int marks;
Int student_id;
```

used constructor & getter/setter

but I don't know where I have to construct hashmap in this Pojo class.

Comment: I  think you have misread or misunderstood your assignment.  Probably `semesterMap` is supposed to be a `Map` not a `String`.

Comment: You could add a toHashMap()-method to your class..

Comment: @StephenC yes, Thanks for correcting me. Now it's done and thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple way is to call a HashMap method on the object when needed.

For example this could look like this:

```
    public HashMap<String, Integer> toHashMap() {
        return new HashMap<>() {{
            put("marks", this.marks);
            put("stunden_id", this.student_id);
        }};
    }
```